# how to get public ip of the client in php

Tags: php

I have to get public IP of the remote system in php.
I have tried

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
```

but is always returning the private IP. Help to fix it.

Comment: Did you try `$_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the client IP address in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php)

Comment: Ya i tried $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] also @Michelem

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ip = !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] : (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

**Warning:** you should extend it and sanitize, since headers can be easily manipulated.

Comment: When i try $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] in online phpfiddle it is returning the both private and public ip but in my server is empty is there any thing to be done in php ini file ??

Answer (score 0):

```
private function getIP()
{
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $forward;
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $remote;
    }

    return $ip;
}
echo getIP();
```